# Is it possible/recommended to set user roles inside of the actual database instead of rules?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-storage

I'm new to Firebase and I want to make a react-redux aplication conected to a Firebase database that has interfaces that changes acording to the user role. I have been reading the docs and for the user management you have to set the rules for your user roles. I want to know if instead of doing that, I can just store the user roles inside the database itself. And if I can how it should be done.

Comment: you should remove the reactjs tag

Comment: You have to enforce user access via database rules. Consider using custom user attributes for setting user roles. It is the recommended and most efficient solution: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims